# Manhwa where the female lead has two spirits

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead is the daughter of a duke, I can't remember if she is adopted or not. She has two spirits. One is called Alpha and takes the shape of a blue wolf and the other takes the form of a small red dragon. I also remember that her escort knight is from a family that isn't friendly to the duke's family. I also remember that the duke and the knights go missing because of a dragon's illusion and the female lead takes over as acting lord for a while, which leads her to fighting an enemy army by flooding a river they are crossing.

Comment: Those are some good details. Was this in black and white, or color? Do you remember the lead's hair color? Was she native to the world, or was this an isekai situation? Reincarnation? Did you read this in paper format, or online? If you didn't read it in the original language, how did the scanlation look? Do you remember anything about the group that translated and uploaded it (sometimes they have a catchy image for the group at the end)?

Comment: I wrote manga but now that i think about it, it was in colour so I think it might have been a manhwa and I think she had silver hair. I also remember she used a bow not much but that was her weapon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *I Am a Child of this House* / *[I Belong to House Castiello](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-belong-to-house-castielo)*.

> 11-year-old Estelle never imagined she’d be sold off by her own mother. But the buyer is the one and only duke in the empire, Ein Castielo… and he’s Estelle’s father?! Feared across kingdoms for his blood-red eyes and the immense powers of his magical lineage, Ein is the cold master of House Castielo. His sworn enemies and dashing knights could become Estelle’s, but does being his rare daughter really mean she is a child of this house?

### Alpha

[image: Image of Alpha, a blue wolf]

### End

[image: Image of End, a red dragon]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by including more details of the story, so the answer stands on its own.

Comment: Also, you will be able to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour], although as a self-answer, you'll not be able to finalize it for another two days.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept.